# Send message to background.js from options.js in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can find plenty of questions for sending a message from Bbackground to content scripts or from popup to background scripts, but I can't find any on how to send a message from `options.js` (triggered from my options page) to `background.js` for my Chrome extension

`manifest.js`

```js
{
  ...
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "alarms",
    "contextMenus",
    "notifications",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "icons": {
    "48": "/assets/icons/icon-48.png",
    "128": "/assets/icons/icon-128.png"
  }
}
```

Code in `options.js`

```js
// Save options
document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  // Check for selected regions
  let selectedRegions = [];
  regionChecks.forEach(elm => {
    if (elm.checked)
      selectedRegions.push(elm.id.replace('region-', ''))
  });
  // Save selections
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'regions': selectedRegions });

  // Check for refresh period
  let refreshPeriod = document.querySelector('#refresh');
  if (refreshPeriod) {
    refreshPeriod = parseInt(refreshPeriod.value);
    if (refreshPeriod === NaN) {
      refreshPeriod = 5;
    } else if(refreshPeriod < 2) {
      refreshPeriod = 2;
    } else if (refreshPeriod > 120) {
      refreshPeriod = 120;
    }
    // Save period
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'refresh': refreshPeriod });
  }

  // Loop through features and remove if region gone
  chrome.storage.local.get(['features'], featuresData => {
    let featureCount = 0;
    if (featuresData.features) {
      featureSet = featuresData.features;
      Object.keys(featureSet).forEach(key => {
        if (!selectedRegions.includes(featureSet[key].Region)) {
          delete featureSet[key];
        } else if (featureSet[key].Status !== "read") {
          featureCount = featureCount + 1;
        }
      });
      // Update features data
      chrome.storage.local.set({ 'features': featureSet });
      // Update the badge
      if (featureCount > 0) {
        chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: featureCount.toString() });
      } else {
        chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: '' });
      }
    }
  });

  // Trigger an update
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('', {
    type: 'update'
  });

  // Close the options page
  close();
});
```

Code in `background.js`

```js
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(data => {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.type === 'update') {
    scheduleRequest();
  }
});
```

But nothing is happening

I've tried using `tabs.sendMessage`, but even if I put `tabs` in permissions it tells me that it isn't defined when I add it to the function `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {...`

Comment: 1) Remove `'',` from sendMessage. 2) [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029), 3) Maybe move `close()` into the callback of sendMessage.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, this did it! :D If you want to post 1 and 3 as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some input from @woxxom and @Norio, and a little bit more troubleshooting, this is how I managed to get it to work

option.js:

```js
// Trigger an update
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'update' }, result => {
  // Close the options page
  close();
});
```

I had to move the `close();` event into the return function so it didn't prematurely close off the code. I also had to have a paramter in the return function for some reason otherwise it wouldn't run with an empty arrow function.

background.js:

```js
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.type === 'update') {
    startRequest(true).then(sendResponse);
    return true;
  }
});
```

My function to be triggered in the `background.js` file was already an async promise function, so I had to add a `.then()` for the `onMessage` response function to trigger once it had run. It also wouldn't work without having `return true;` in there.

Answer (score 0):

My test results contradict your claim.

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

background.js

```js
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(data => {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.type === 'update') {
    console.log("hoge")
    //    scheduleRequest();
  }
});
```

options.js

```js
// Trigger an update
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('', {
  type: 'update'
});
```

options.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  options page
  <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I forgot something vital in my `options.js` file example. That code is only running after I click save. I've just tested my code again and it's not showing a console still.

Comment: I think you should post all files.

Comment: Prove that chrome.runtime.sendMessage in options.js is called.

Comment: I've posted my full code in that function. Everything else in that function is working just fine, it's just not triggering anything in my `background.js`. Everything else in my `background.js` file is also running with no problems. I just seem to be having an issue with the `sendMessage`

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line calling chrome.runtime.sendMessage() in options.js and make sure it breaks.